# PHP "parse error, expecting `T_STRING' " - Please help with code

Tags: php, wamp

I'm trying to build a dynamic php site using MVC principles.  I'm using WAMP on Win XP.

Here's the code:

Index.php:

```
<?php
  require_once("User.php");
  session_start();
  include ("Header.php");
  include ("Footer.php");
?>
```

Header.php:

```
<?php
  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
<head>
  <title><?php echo "temp"; ?></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="StyleSheetProjet" href="StyleSheetProjet.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="connectionStatus">
    <?php
    ?>
  </div>
```

Footer.php:

```
</body>
</html>
```

User.php:

```
<?php
  class User {
    private $userName;
    private $hashedPassword;
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $userEmail;

    function $getUserName() {
      return $this->userName;
    }
  }
?>
```

This code causes a php error on line 9 of User.php, i.e., at the get function declaration.  The error message is:

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' in C:\wamp\www\Projet\User.php on line 9
```

Help would be very much appreciated....

Thanks,

JDelage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function $getUserName()
```

should be

```
function getUserName()
```

After the `function` keyword, PHP expects a whitespace followed by an `identifier`(function name). But in your case it finds a `variable` and this causes a **parse error**.

Internally an identifier is called `T_STRING` and a variable is called `T_VARIABLE`. Some PHP interpreters throw:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING ....

Others, as in your case just say:

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' ....

Answer (score 3):

You have typo in your function name. Currently it's `$getUserName` where it should be `getUserName` (without $).

Answer (score 3):

`function`<strike>`$`</strike>`getUserName()`

Answer (score 3):

You can't use variable substitution when declaring functions.

This:

```
function $getUserName()
```

should be this:

```
function getUserName()
```

Answer (score 2):

Function names does not need $ sign at the beginning.

Do it like that:

```
function getUserName() {
  return $this->userName;
}
```